# Help me to find integration factor and solve the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

$\left ( 2y +xy^{3} \right )dx + \left ( x+x^{2}y^{2} \right )dy=0$

Help me i have no idea to do it 
[image]

Comment: please show your efforts or works after that people can help you

Comment: Please type out the working, don't just post a photo. Photos take time to load, are not searchable on the site, and can't be seen by some people on the site. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial, for typing Maths nicely, if you need it

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

look at your final step and note that $x+x^2y^2=x(1+xy^2)$